# How to perform a matrix rotation of an information matrix

Tags: kalman-filter

Within the Information Filter, the "inverse" of the Kalman Filter, resides the Information Matrix $Y$, which is itself the inverse of a covariance matrix, $P$, such that $Y=P^{-1}$.

Now, as clarified in [this StackExchange question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2556/how-to-rotate-covariance), a covariance matrix can be rotated by a rotation matrix $R_{1\rightarrow2}$ by way of $P_2 = RP_1R^T$. How can this transformation be done entirely in the information space, such that we can use $R$ to get from $Y_1$ to $Y_2$?

The rotation matrix being orthogonal, would the correct method of rotating the information matrix be $Y_2 = R^TY_1R$?

Comment: So you mean given that $Y_1=P_1^{-1}$ and $P_2 = RP_1R^\top$ how to express $Y_2=P_2^{-1}$ as a function of $Y_1$ and $R$?

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find the expression for $Y_2$ as a function of $Y_1$ and $R$ one needs to use that the inverse of a product of matrices requires inverting each of the matrices and reversing the multiplication order, $(A\,B)^{-1}=B^{-1} A^{-1}$, and that the inverse of a rotation matrix is equal to its transpose. Combining this yields that

\begin{align}
Y_2 &= P_2^{-1}, \\
&= (R\,P_1 R^\top)^{-1}, \\
&= R^{-\top}\,P_1^{-1} R^{-1}, \\
&= R\,Y_1 R^\top.
\end{align}